# Symfony2 IP restriction to everyone

Tags: symfony, ip

I'm trying to apply an IP restriction to specific routes in Symfony2, as described on [Symfony2 book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#securing-by-ip). I have no user authentication, I just want that my service answers to requests that come from a specific IP.

But I don't succeed to apply the restriction (I always pass through during my tests).

Here's my security.yml

```
jms_security_extra:
    secure_all_services: false
    expressions: true

security:
    encoders:
            Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                   user:  { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
                   admin: { password: adminpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }

    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            pattern: ^/wsoa/tests
            anonymous: ~
            # http_basic:
                # realm: "Secured Demo Area"

    access_control:
        #- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
        #- { path: ^/_internal/secure, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ip: 127.0.0.1 }
        # THE RESTRICTION I'D LIKE (FOR EXEMPLE 127.0.0.1)
        - { path: ^/wsoa_products_tests, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ip: 127.0.0.1 }
```

And here is my route from routing.yml:

```
wsoa_products_tests:
    pattern:  /wsoa/tests
    defaults: { _controller: WsoaProductsBundle:Test:display }
```

Anyone knows how to make it works ?
Should I forget to do this in Symfony2 and do this with htaccess ?

Answer (score 5):

To restrict a path to only specific IPs you can add the following to your `security.yml` access_control:

```
- { path: ^/yourpath, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ips: [1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.2, ...]  }
- { path: ^/yourpath, roles: ROLE_NO_ACCESS }
```

And if you want to restrict to a full range of IPs, use an IP netmask, like this:

```
- { path: ^/yourpath, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ips: [1.1.1.0/24]  }
- { path: ^/yourpath, roles: ROLE_NO_ACCESS }
```

Note: the IP addresses I've put here need to be replaced with the ones you want to restrict. Also replace `^/yourpath` with your actual path or subpath.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use routes in the access_control configuration.  Instead, try securing a sub path, IE:

```
- { path: ^/wsoa, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ip: 127.0.0.1 }
```

Then routes that should be secured use the prefix.

```
wsoa_products_tests:
    pattern:  /wsoa/tests
    defaults: { _controller: WsoaProductsBundle:Test:display }
```

Edit:

You can try implementing a custom voter.. (http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/security/voters.html)

Use the class suggested in that document, and then you can overlay the vote method with something like:

```
function vote(TokenInterface $token, $object, array $attributes)
{
    $request = $this->container->get('request');

    $route = $request->get('_route');

    // I suggest passing the allowed routes in the service definition instead of
    // hardcoding here, but for example sake:

    if (in_array($route, array('wsoa_product_tests'))) {
        if (in_array($request->getClientIp(), $this->blacklistedIp)) {
            return VoterInterface::ACCESS_DENIED;
        }
    }

    return VoterInterface::ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily block IP and ranges of IP using my bundle => https://github.com/Spomky/SpomkyIpFilterBundle

Comment: This bundle is now unmaintained, as written on Github.